# Sort orders by quantity and even show where quantity was 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I've written this bit of SQL: it returns the Items sold past the month of November. However, I want to show *all* items that were sold and just to stick a 0 next to the one where it didn't sell in that month.
Would appreciate some guidance:

```
SELECT ItemID, SUM(Quantity)
FROM orderitems
WHERE OrderNumber IN(
    SELECT OrderNumber
    FROM `order`
    WHERE OrderDate > "2015-11-31") GROUP BY ItemID;
```

Comment: Save your sanity. Do not use reserved words as table/column idenitifers.

Comment: Got it, I will change that. Thanks!

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ItemID, 
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE 
                      WHEN o2.OrderDate > '2015-11-31' 
                      THEN Quantity 
                    END), 0) AS Sum_Of_Quantity 
FROM orderitems AS o1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT OrderNumber, OrderDate
           FROM `order`
           WHERE OrderDate > '2015-11-31') AS o2
   ON o1.OrderNumber = o2.OrderNumber
GROUP BY ItemID;
```

Comment: Apologies. But what that did is count up all the items as opposed to from within the timeframe.

Comment: Sorry, where is the c2 coming from on line 3?

Comment: @ak1652 That was a typo. Should be `o2.OrderDate`, that is the date value from `order` table.

Answer (score 0):

One more table is needed here: the one with full list of items whether ever ordered or not.

Then it would be:

```
SELECT
    FullListOfItemsOnSale.ItemID,
    IFNULL(OrdetedItems.Quantity, 0) AS Quantity
FROM FullListOfItemsOnSale
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ItemID, SUM(i.Quantity) AS Quantity
    FROM orderitems i
    INNER JOIN `order` o ON o.OrderNumber = i.OrderNumber
                        AND o.OrderDate > "2015-11-31"
) OrdetedItems ON OrdetedItems.ItemID = FullListOfItemsOnSale.ItemID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ItemID, 
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN c2.OrderDate > '2015-11-31' THEN Quantity END), 0) Sum_Of_Quantity 
FROM orderitems AS o1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT OrderNumber, OrderDate
           FROM `order`
           WHERE OrderDate > '2015-11-31') AS o2
   ON o1.OrderNumber = o2.OrderNumber
GROUP BY ItemID;
```